# Scroll to selection in an ExtJS Grid

Tags: extjs, grid

Hey, i need to be able to scroll my ExtJS grid to the current selection but have no idea how to do this. I came across a reference in a forum to an ensureVisible method but can find no information. Can anyone make any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm being really dumb. I just tried ensureVisible and it works fine.

Comment: @Erik Allik - We use ExtJS 3.4. I would be surprised if it did not work in 4.0.

Answer (score 9):

This also seems to work:

```
grid.getView().focusRow(rowIdx);
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately ensureVisible() was removed from ExtJS 4. The most straight-forward solution I found is to use scrollIntoView(). In my case, this was after selecting the row based on a value I loaded.

```
var rowIndex = store.find('fieldName', value);
grid.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex);
Ext.fly(grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex)).scrollIntoView();
```

This will show the selected row at the bottom of the grid. More work would need to be done to have it at the top or middle of the grid.

Comment: You should use a fly element for operations like this  `Ext.fly(grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex)).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Hey CTarczon, can you please give me a little idea of how to focus and move it to the top of the grid?

Comment: Don't know why, but `.scrollIntoView()` doesn't work for me in Ext 4.2. Fortunately a simple `.focus()` on the returned node does the trick ;)

Answer (score 5):

This also seems to work:

```
    grid.getView().getRow(rowIdx).scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me on ExtJS 6, even with bufferedRenderer turned on.

```
        var record = grid.getSelectionModel().selected.getRange()[0];
        grid.getView().focusRow(record);
```

Comment: ...On a non-buffered grid.

Answer (score 2):

This also seems to work

```
grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex).scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
```

In case of ExtJs 4.X No need to use `Ext.fly`

Comment: 'evil IE', scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() works in chrome, Please refer answer by @bhuvaneswari for IE , also  'scrollIntoView()' gives weird behavior if you are using modal windows

Answer (score 0):

To save you all a lot of hair pulling, you should know that the solutions in this thread for scrolling into view will **not** work if grid **bufferedRenderer** is turned on.

It is my understanding that in Ext JS 5, bufferedRenderer is turned on by default.

It took me a couple hours before I realized this.

grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex) will return NULL if the indexed row is outside the buffered rows.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.2 at least, using `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` fails if you're outside of the buffered range in a bufferedRenderer.  The bufferedRenderer has a handy `scrollTo` method to help with this task though:

```
grid.getView().bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(index, true);
```

> Scrolls to and optionlly selects the specified row index in the total dataset.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer-method-scrollTo