# How to scroll to a specified record in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

**How can we scroll to a defined record (record or index) in a grid?**

Using a buffered renderer this is quite easy by calling:

```
grid.view.bufferedRenderer.scrollTo(0, false, callback, scope);
```

but how can this be done with a default renderer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to selection in an ExtJS Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883326/scroll-to-selection-in-an-extjs-grid)

Comment: @Jandalf I don't have any selection because the record is inserted new! You may also look at the answer which is **totally different**!

Comment: And where do you need a selection here: `grid.getView().focusRow(rowIdx)` http://stackoverflow.com/a/16407352/1453662 it is a dup

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
grid.getView().scrollRowIntoView(rowIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it worked! Btw. it works with a record instance too.

Comment: Yes, if you look into the source code you can see that this method is overloaded. I don't know why, this method is not documented so it should be considered private. Or ask Sencha to document it.